# sql returning three time the same column

Tags: sql

I'm having troubles trying to select three times the user name.

I have a table

```
JOBS (id, id_student, id_professor, id_professor2)
```

This last column is optional, then sometimes NULL is set in its content. When that happens, the query doesn't return any rows. However, if id_professor2 is set, the query returns like I expect. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT 
    p.name as  professor, s.name as student, s_p.name as second_professor
FROM 
    users as p 
JOIN
    jobs ON (p.id = jobs.id_professor) 
JOIN 
    users as s ON (jobs.id_student = s.id) 
JOIN
    users as s_p ON (s_p.id = jobs.id_professor2)
WHERE 
    jobs.id = 2;
```

The job with id=2 has an second professor, so the query runs normally. But if a change for `jobs.id=3` the query doesn't return anything.

Comment: I fixed. That happend because I addapted to English to post here and forgot some details.

Comment: I'm guessing that `users as s_p ON(c.id = jobs.id_professor2)` should `users as s_p ON(s.id = jobs.id_professor2)` too since `c` is never aliased..

Comment: Thanks, I fixed. It should be s_p.id

Comment: make your last join to be left outer - this will preserve the data returned from the first two columns of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join

```
SELECT p.name as  professor, a.name as student, s_p.name as second_professor
FROM  users as p
JOIN jobs ON(p.id = jobs.id_professor)
JOIN users as s ON(jobs.id_student = a.id)
left outer
JOIN users as c ON(c.id = jobs.id_professor2)
WHERE jobs.id = 2
;
```